# Is there a reliable VOIP setup?

Tags: networking, voip, fiber

I'm in [Tasmania, Australia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasmania).

We are about to get our second [fibre cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basslink#Communications_cable) lit up.

Up till now, latency & reliability have been major issues in the take-up of VOIP.

Considering this, can you recommend a VOIP setup for small to medium business' (1-50 employees)?

Call quality (signal to noise ratio), latency and hardware have all been issues in the past.

I'm familiar with http://www.asterisk.org/. Are there other setups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do VOIP and it seems every hardware vendor is now providing equipment for it.

1. Decide on your end points.  Currently we are running VIOP inside the office but we are using a POTS provider once we hit the edge of the office.  At some point we will look at connecting to an external VOIP provider but we have a current contract to run out first.  Most systems can even do a mix of POTS and VOIP if you want a failover
2. Talk to a SIP provider they should be able to give you good estimates on how much bandwidth would be needed based on how many concurrent calls you need to run
3. Look at your Hardware options.  Everyone from Avaya to Asterisk runs voip now.  We purchased a Switchvox system from Digium (The makers of asterisk) and have been happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [3CX](http://www.3cx.com).